# How to set sub query result as variable in hive script

Tags: sql, variables, hiveql

I'm looking for something like

```
SET hivevar:varname = (select max(server_date) from myTable);

SELECT * FROM foo WHERE day >= ${hivevar:varname};
```

But the problem is second query is giving error because hivevar:varname is a table and we cannot use a table in where clause.

Can anyone give alternate approach to do this. Or is there anyway to store subquery result to hivevar as a string or datetime object.

Comment: You can store a table as a temporary *table*.  Alternatively, you can use a CTE.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I can store result in either temporary table or can use CTE or in hivevar. But how can i use its result in 'WHERE' clause with '>=' predicate.